# How to get updated and rendered value of axis in NVD3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am working with NVD3.js library for creating my chart. In my website, I receive a new data every 5 second. I add and update my chart. It's working fine. My problem  is that I want to get the new rendered and updated range for either x-Axis or y-Axis. But my code return same value every time.

```
d3.select( "#chart" + panelId + " svg" )
.datum( getData( data ) );
log( chart.xAxis.scale().domain() ); // Before updating
chart.update();
log( chart.xAxis.scale().domain() ); // After updating
```

How can I get the updated range of x-Axis and y-Axis?

Comment: probably need to wait for the `renderEnd` event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @WhiteHat, I did it by catching the "renderEnd" event of the chart as below:

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on("renderEnd", () => {
  // Handle render event here
  log( "Rendered");
}
);
```